# Surjectivity of x^2 - floor(x)^2

Tags: functions, proof-writing

How would I go about proving $f(x) = x^2 - \lfloor x\rfloor^2$ is surjective when $f: \mathbb{R}^{\geq 0} \to \mathbb{R}^{\geq 0} $?

Not sure where to start...
I believe it's true but but it almost seems too easy but proving it is a challenge for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $t \geq 0$. Choose any $n >\frac {t-1} 2$ and take $x =\sqrt {t+n^{2}}$. Then $f(x)=t$.  [You can check that $n \leq x \leq n+1$. So $f(x)=x^{2}-n^{2}=t$].

Comment: Why does $f(x) = t$?

Comment: @LetmeKnow I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* The image of the interval $[n,n+1)$ is $[0,1+2n)$.

*Spoiler:*

> $x=n+y$ with $y \in [0,1)$ implies $f(x)=y^2+2ny$.

Here is a [plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%5E2+-+floor%28x%29%5E2+for+x%3D0+to+10):

[image]